# OpenCV similarity to WebGL

Tags: opencv, webgl

I want to do large calculations with OpenCV and I'd like to know exactly where OpenCV does it's GPU calculations (i.e. in the main function). I believe WebGL performs GPU operations in a shaderProgram, but what's the equivalent in OpenCv?

thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: AFAIK WebGL and OpenCV are not really comparable. WebGL is extremely low-level where you have to write custom shader programs to do anything. [OpenCV is high level](https://docs.opencv.org/master/index.html). There are hundreds of high level functions you call, how they operate is hidden (could be CPU, could be GPU, could be a combination), they just return the results requested. For example see [this sample](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/dbt_face_detection.cpp). you just give it data, ask it for faces and it gives them to you. Very high level.

Comment: Do you mean OpenCL. Because OpenCV and webgl or GPUs are completeley unrelated.

Comment: thanks guys for your response. I meant opencv, I don't believe OpenCL will work in my use case. In any case I believe opencv can run on the gpu for large computations but it sounds like when that is is hidden to the user.

Comment: Ok, so I've done some more research and it seems I really want to go low level programming with this. I just want to do super fast computations on the gpu and write pixels to screen. that's all. I don't care about the setup time involved in doing something like this in assembly but I need to write super optimized code to the Pi's broadcom video card. I don't want to use OpenGL either as that seems like it'd be the better choice over opencv or cl which I mentioned above.  Does anyone know exactly how I can start writing assembly to the gpu. I need to go super basic on this one.

Comment: It's possible to write VideoCore IV assembly and assemble it using [third party tools](https://github.com/maazl/vc4asm/) but frankly I would advise against doing so considering your apparent lack of knowledge regarding the subject matter. I think you'd be better off going through either OpenCL kernels or OpenGL ES shaders first, that way you get a feeling of how GPUs operate while still having access to proper toolchains. Writing bare metal GPU assembly for a target without an emulator and only a third party assembler(that's version 0.3) is a pain in the butt even for seasoned assembly coders.

Comment: Also depending on your usecase optimized GLSL might already get you as fast as 95% compared to handwritten assembly. Jumping straight to assembly is a premature optimization either way.

Comment: perhaps you're right. what would the purpose of an emulator be?  In short what I'm doing is using my own algorithms to perform 3d projection rather than using WebGL/OpenGLs pre-done solution. I know they package that 3d projection and rotation up for programmers but as a matter of personal interest I want to do all that myself. I've implemented this in a WebGL shader program but I'm guessing that's inefficient since it was intended for programmers to use the predone 3d projection method. Keeping this in mind, would you now say that assembly is better?

Comment: *"I know they package that 3d projection and rotation up for programmers"* no they don't.

Comment: there are no standard packaged functions to do 3d projection/perspective/rotation for you in WebGL or OpenGL? I'm just curious. I know how to do this stuff but I just want to be sure you're saying there aren't already shader functions for this. thanks for your answers so far. super helpful.

Comment: WebGL1 includes geometric functions that  operates on v2,v3,v4 vectors. And component-wise  matrix operations that operates on m2,m3,m4 matrices.  Projection and Rotation is typically performed by applying a mvp matrix to the vector.  WebGL2 expands the number matrix operations to include outer-product, transpose, determinant and inverse.

Comment: that was super helpful. thanks